Conman fault? Or do I make a mistake?
I have used a wireless connection with conman that is new to me, as on my new notebook I am using debian linux lxqt with version 12 bookworm .
Now I did install some new devices that do not use dhcp from the start. So I had to manage to get direct connected to the devices that I did install. Because of it I did use the command: ifconfig wlo1 add 192.168.0.241 ; ifconfig wlo1:0 broadcast 192.168.0.255
As far this worked for me to reach the device in this area (192.168.0.0/24) to set it up for a net like 192.168.178.x All worked to this point well but now I had some information to read from the ethernet and did realise that I wasn't able to reach it.
my interface wlo1 was right set and visible with ifconfig and with route -n I got some answer like:

0.0.0.0  192.168.178.1 0.0.0.0  UG


192.168.178.0  0.0.0.0  255.255.255.0  U


192.168.0.0  0.0.0.0  255.255.255.0  U

but I did not got a ping to 192.168.178.1 and could not go for the ethernet.
My question is now - as I did not check quick and had to go soon, is his a well known bug or does conman something that I do not expect of it. It's anyway that I think about to change it out as it doesn't remembers routes and that is worse if you are very often in places where there are some subnet things that are not known from everybody.
